# how to create an array from separate variables using a loop in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have around 130 different variables that contain numeric values
The variables are something like `ratio70, ratio71, ratio72,...ratio220`.
So, the variables run from `70` to `220` and I want to create an array out of this so that I can further use this array for plotting a graph
I have tried

```
    ratioarr= (np.array(ratio%i) for i in range (70,220))
```

but this doesn't work either. I don't want to type all the variable names to form the array. Is there an easier method?

Comment: Why are there so many variables?  Might there be a better way to structure the data first?

Comment: Those variables were formed after making gaussian fits to hundreds of spectral lines (in Astronomy) and then calculating the area under the gaussian curve. So each variable was created separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval()` to dynamically make variable names on the go:

`print([eval('ratio' + str(i)) for i in range(70, 221)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the locals() or globals() dictionary, they contain all the variables in the local and global scope, respectively.
So maybe something like:

```
ratioarr = np.array([locals()["ratio" + str(i)] for i in range (70,220)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exec function in a loop to create an array like so

```py
ratioarr = list()
for x in range(70,220):
    exec(f"ratioarr.append(ratio{x})")
```